Почему код работает не так как нужно?
Я пытаюсь запустить код который будет от моего имени каждый час отправлять сообщения в мою группу. Но по какой то причине он отправляет сообщения только мне в избранное, а не в группу. Что не так в коде? Библиотека telethon установлена.
from telethon import TelegramClient
import time

api_id = ...
api_hash = '...'

with TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(
        client.send_message('me', 'Hello!')
    )

async def main():
    while True:
        await client.send_message(1002172163245, '/Любой текст - тест 33/')

        time.sleep(60)

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())


Ссылку на картинку потеряли, поэтому она не отображается.

Вы отправляете в чат или в канал? Он открытый?
Если отправляете в канал, то всё должно работать по вашему коду, но канал должен быть публичным, судя по коду, который написали вы (судя по ID).
Можете посмотреть подробнее, как это работает, в моём проекте на GitHub.
В вашем коде ID указан 1002172163245, я таких ID в ТГ не видел. Есть -100XXXXXXXXX, это ID для "супергрупп" и каналов.
Попробуйте добавить "-" перед id

Да ! Ты был прав, не хватало тире. Спасибо!  Что касаемо не правильных цифр - так я их специально заменил - чтобы не палить свои данные

Можешь подсказать - как мне прописать в коде так - что был скрипт писал в определенную ветку группы, а то он только в генерал пишет . Пытаюсь интегрировать эту строчку - но пока без успешно         ...  await bot.send_message(chat_id={ID группы}, message_thread_id={ID Ветка группы},text="12345")
